Schengen visa for parents without Verpflichtungserklärungen document
I am inviting my parents to visit me in Germany for 2 months at my apartment. Due to a lot of rush at auslaenderbehoerde, I was not able to get hold of Verpflichtungserklärungen document on time, so they will be declaring themselves as self sponsored.
The thing is I have sufficient proof of income to support them (Payslips) but I am not sure if they consider it without Verpflichtungserklärungen document.

Do we really require Verpflichtungserklärungen document to stay at
my apartment?
I will be sending them formally signed invitation
letter along with my RP. Do we need to send house contract as well?
In the application -> Travel and Living costs -> Do we need to check
both options - 1)by him/herself 2) Inviting person
Can we select "Assumption of all expenses during the stay" in the last section of "Means of Support" without sponsorship document?
Can we mention that I will be supporting them as well in the cover letter or will it unnecessarily become the reason of rejection

Thank you and appreciate any help on this!

I’m confused. Are they self-sponsored (and have the documents to prove it), or not?

They are self sponsored and they will be providing bank statements, ITR and property papers. They do not have monthly pensions as such but they get in form of rent amount and we can show FD statements if neccessary

As a partial answer, I think you are mixing several different concepts in your question:

A Verpflichtungserklärung is a pledge to pay the German state for the costs of (intentional or unintentional) overstays.

A Verpflichtungserklärung will not be necessary if the applicant has strong finances and ties to the homland, it will not be sufficient if the finances and ties to the homeland are very weak. The Verpflichtungserklärung matters if the application is neither very strong nor very weak.
When a German resident gives such a pledge, the authorities want to check if the resident can afford to repay costs. That is mostly a matter of income, but there may also be a check if the resident can house the applicant in the existing housing.
If the financial situation of the person giving the Verpflichtungserklärung is weak, the state may demand a deposit.


Any visa application needs to explain where the funds for the travel come from.

The best case is a stable, well-paid, well-documented job with enough money left over to afford travel.
If someone else pays for the travel, there needs to be an explanation why that person will pay (e.g. "the applicants are my parents"), where that money comes from, and if the person can afford it. That is not quite the same as sponsorship in other countries.


To have visitors in your housing for more than a few days, there are two issues to consider:

There are public health and welfare restrictions how many people can live in a house or apartment. The minimum area depends on the federal state, but they will be around 10 m2 per person. More people may not live in a place, regardless of visa status. (Typical German housing is larger than that ...)
If you are a tenant, your contract with the landlord will limit who can live in your flat. You need the permission of your landlord if more people move in with you. You do not need the permission for a brief visit.



So your payslips will explain where the funds of your parents will come from, but that is less than a formal pledge to pay for them.

I would add that the difference between a brief visit and moving in is not rigorously defined but a period of 2 months as planned by OP is long enough that a landlord may reasonably consider it as (temporarily) moving in. So I would suggest to talk to the landlord and ask them if they are ok with this.

I have signed lots of Verpflichtungserklärungen over the years and I believe I have never been asked about the size of my appartment. They usually just want my ID, my payslips, and the data of the applicant. I think the Ausländerbehörde does not even check if we are really related (I believe that is done by the embassy)

@Jan, I believe that says good things about your payslips. And relationships are not required for the Verpflichtungserklärung, but they will be helpful when it comes to explaining sudden deposits in the parents' accounts.

Those Verpflichtungserklärung that I have seen had a field for Verwandtschaftsverhältnis. And I have signed Verpflichtungserklärungen without payslips (i.e. with deposit)

The bit about accomodation might vary from place to place. E.g. Aachen asks for your rent contract, Berlin does not.
